# Modifying arrays with 'duplicate' values and rendering with a template

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

The behavior I am seeing with a small 'array input' polymer element is getting the best of me. I've created an input that accepts multiple values. Internally the values are stored in an 'Array' property and displayed with a  tag. This seems to work as intended.

Once a value is added (using Enter), it is boxed up in the arraybox, then an input for a new value is focused. I would like to be able to click on values that are already added and modify them in the input. Right now, it splices the value from the array, and adds its value to the input.

However -- when doing so, clicking (and coincidentally splicing) will render the duplicate value 'blank'. Fetching a getValue() function will return a perfect array. Clicking on the 'blanked' out values will result in a correct value in the input.

Here's a 'watered down' version of the element that still exhibits the behavior.

```
<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<template>
  <array-items id="values">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
      <array-item style='padding:5px;margin-right:5px;background-color:lightblue;'>{{item}}</array-item>
    </template>
    <input id="input">
  </array-items>
</template>
```

```
Polymer({ 
  is: 'app-arraybox',

  properties: {
    // Items are the 'entries' inside the array-box
    items: {
      type: Object,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      value: []
    },

  },

  listeners: {
    'input.keydown': '_inputKeys',
    'input.blur': '_addValue',
    'values.click': '_itemClick',
  },

  _inputKeys: function(event) {
    var backspace = 8;
    var enter = 13;
    // If enter, then add a new value
    if (event.keyCode == enter)
        this._addValue();
    // if backspace (and input is empty), then edit the last value
    else if (event.keyCode == backspace) {
        if (this.$.input.value.length < 1) {
          event.preventDefault();
          this._editValue();
        }
      }
  },

  // Handle clicking on an existing item
  _itemClick: function(event) {
    // Return if not clicking on an array-item -- this is bound
    // to the container since items don't exist in the DOM yet
    if (event.target.tagName != 'ARRAY-ITEM') return;
    var child = event.target;
    var input = this.$.input;
    // Figure out index of clicked item by iterating through previousSiblings and checking them
    var i = 0; while((child = child.previousSibling) != null) { 
      // only count ARRAY-ITEMS
      if (child.tagName == 'ARRAY-ITEM') i++; 
    } 
    // Before continuing, if there's a value in the input already, add it to the arraybox
    if (input.value.length > 0) this._addValue();
    // Splice the value from 'this.items' and add the value to the input for editing
    this.$.input.value = this.splice('items', i, 1);
    // And finally, focus the input
    this.$.input.focus();
  },

  _addValue: function() {
    // Need the input, and value of the input
    var input = this.$.input;
    var value = input.value;
    // Value must be at least a single character
    if (value.length > 0) {
      // Push the value to the array
      this.push('items', value);
      // Clear the text input
      input.value = '';
    } else {
      // No 'meaningful' value was input
    }
  },

  _editValue: function() {
    var input = this.$.input;
    if (this.items.length == 0)
      return;
      // Set the input to the last value in the array (pop also removes it from the array)
    input.value = this.pop('items');
  },

  _updateIcon: function() {
    // Check if icon is set and set <iron-icon> attribute if necessary
    if (this.icon.length > 0)
      this.$.icon.setAttribute('icon', this.icon);
    // Else, remove the attribute on the <iron-icon>
    else this.$.icon.removeAttribute('icon');
  },

  // Public 'getValue' for API/JavaScript interaction
  getValue: function() {
    // Return items array
    return this.items;
  },

});
```

Please tell me I'm doing something stupid. 
You can see a demo here: [app-arraybox demo](http://tinyurl.com/arraybox)

Comment: As a suggestion in the Polymer slack channel, I've resorted to storing single-value Objects inside the array, as opposed to Strings. This works, however an explanation would still be cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer relies on object-identity to optimize dom-repeat rendering in the face of changing data. When your data is concrete (simple Numbers or Strings), a datum has no identity (one 'foo' is the same as any other 'foo'). If you store object based data instead (`{text: 'foo'}`) each object is unique.

Also, you should not assume in general that dom-node indices correspond to array indices, because you may want to sort/filter your view in the future.

Lastly, there are a number of affordances that Polymer provides for working with collections and repeats (and various other tasks) that you are not taking advantage of. For example, your `itemClick` can be collapsed to something like this:

```
// Handle clicking on an existing item
_itemClick: function(event) {
  // get the item reference from the event
  var item = event.model.item;
  // remove item from array
  this.arrayDelete('items', item);
  // return item text to edit mode
  this.value = item.text;
  this.$.input.focus();
},
```

Here is a version in live form (Chrome only, for convenience):

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  
  <meta name="description" content="color-thief with Polymer">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">

  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

  <style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #999;
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <app-arraybox icon="menu"></app-arraybox>

  <!--
  [ APP-ARRAYBOX | BY JEREMY SCHROEDER | ... ]
  Multi-value input boxes that hold values as an array.
  -->

  <!-- 'dom-module' is a Polymer element that registers arbitrary content by an `id`-->

  <dom-module id="app-arraybox">

<!-- The style contained is relative to the element itself and will not style
     anything outside. To style the element itself, use the ':host' specifier -->

<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
    cursor: text;
  }

  :host.raised {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-bottom: 4px solid lightgray;
    border-right: 4px solid lightgray;
    padding-left: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  iron-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  iron-icon[icon] {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 8px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-left: 6px;
  }

  input {
    flex: 1 1;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 6px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 12px;
    font-size: 100%;
  }

  array-item {
    flex: none;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    top: 7px;
    position: relative;
    height: 21px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  array-items {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

</style>

<!-- The template contains the markup of the element itself. <content></content> can be used to pass along
      any 'inner text' that the user specifies. There are also a slew of 'helpers' such as template repeating,
      data binding, and event registration that can be taken advantage of here. -->
<template>

  <array-items id="values">

    <iron-icon id="icon" icon$="{{icon}}"></iron-icon>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
      <array-item on-click="_itemClick">{{item.text}}</array-item>
    </template>

    <input id="input" value="{{value::input}}" on-blur='_commitValue' on-keydown="_inputKeys">

  </array-items>

</template>

<!-- The script contains is called upon registration. Though it typically includes a call to Polymer(...), it can also
     include other code that can be used to manage the element and its features. -->
<script>

  Polymer({

    // Required -- tells Polymer which element is being registered. If there is a dom-module
    // registered with the same value for `id`, Polymer will look in that dom-module for 
    // templates and style-sheets.
    is: 'app-arraybox',

    // Properties registered here can be accessed via 'this' at any time. 
    properties: {

      // Items are the 'entries' inside the array-box
      items: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return [];
        }
      },

      // Icon is an iron-icon that can be shown at the beginning of the arraybox (optional)
      icon: {
        type: String,
        reflectToAttribute: true
      }, 

      raised: {
        type: Boolean,
        reflectToAttribute: true,
        value: false,
        observer: '_raise'
      },

      value: {
        value: ''
      }

    },

    // Register listeners -- these will execute functions when the specified event is fired
    listeners: {
      'click': '_focusInput'
    },

    _raise: function() {
      this.toggleClass('raised', this.raised);
    },

    _focusInput: function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName == 'APP-ARRAYBOX')
        this.$.input.focus();
    },

    // Handle 'keyup' for the input
    _inputKeys: function(event) {
      var backspace = 8;
      var enter = 13;
      // If enter, then add a new value
      if (event.keyCode == enter) {
        this._commitValue();
      } else
      // if backspace, then edit the last value
      if (event.keyCode == backspace) {
        if (this.$.input.value.length <= 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          this._editValue();
        }
      }
    },

    // Handle clicking on an existing item
    _itemClick: function(event) {
      // get the item reference from the event
      var item = event.model.item;
      // remove item from array
      this.arrayDelete('items', item);
      // return item text to edit mode
      this.value = item.text;
      this.$.input.focus();
    },

    _commitValue: function() {
      // Value must be at least a single character
      if (this.value.length > 0) {
        console.log('Adding ' + this.value);
        // Push the value to the array
        this.addValue(this.value);
        // Clear the text input
        this.value = '';
      } else {
        // No 'meaningful' value was input
      }
    },

    _editValue: function() {
      // Value must none, otherwise it's a regular 'backspace', in which case we just return without
      // doing anything.
      if (this.items.length > 0) {
        // Set the input to the last value in the array (pop also removes it from the array)
        this.value = this.pop('items');
      }
    },

    // Public 'addValue' for API/JavaScript interaction
    addValue: function(value) {
      // Push new item to the items array
      this.push('items', {text: value});
    },

    // Public 'getValue' for API/JavaScript interaction
    getValue: function() {
      // Return items array
      return this.items;
    },

    setValue: function(array) {
      this.items = array;
    }

  });

</script>

  </dom-module>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Fair enough. I ended up employing something very similar (per your suggestion in other polymer discussion), however thank you for a fuller explaination. +1 for the model properties on event. I see some documentation on that concept in this [Polymer 1.0 dev doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html), so I will check that out. I definitely get the concern with counting elements.